# Intent Redirection Vulnerablity

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-security

I got the following mail from Play Console when I uploaded my Android bundle.

> Intent Redirection Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.
>
> To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center
> article.
>
> com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity.onCreate

My AndroidMainfest has :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:node="merge" />
```

Let me know if someone received a similar mail from Google and was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do
android:exported="false"